# How do i get symbol references in a diagnostic without SymbolFinder?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Currently i've got this code:

```
    private async Task<bool> IsMentionedInDisposeCallAsync(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, FieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclarationSyntax)
    {
        foreach (var variableDeclaratorSyntax in fieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration.Variables)
        {
            var declaredSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variableDeclaratorSyntax);
            if (declaredSymbol is IFieldSymbol fieldSymbol)
            {
//              SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync()
                var b = fieldSymbol.Locations;
//              context.SemanticModel.Compilation.
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And this scenario:

```
private static readonly string TestSourceImplementsDisposableAndDoesMentionDisposableField = @"
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class SampleDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    public class SampleConsumer : IDisposable
    {
        private SampleDisposable _disposable = new SampleDisposable();
        private IDisposable _ms = new MemoryStream();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _disposable?.Dispose();
            _ms?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}";
```

Ultimately my desire is to figure out whether a dispose method is accessing a disposable field. Unfortunately i can't seem to find a way to get this working without using SymbolFinder, which requires a solution.

I did something similar with SymbolFinder and it was an easy thing to do - but how do i do it from the functionality available within a diagnostic?

Am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: What is wrong with having a solution?

Comment: @Sievajet you don't get one from inside a diagnostic on a diagnosis level?

Comment: If you scan for all classes. the analysiscontext holds the symbol for the class. You can then check whether it implements the `IDisposable` interface

Comment: @Sievajet manual scanning then? No built in class? This seems like a basic requirement of what one would do in the scope of a diagnostic. Because that's what i am doing currently, but built in classes are usually capable of more than that.

Comment: You basically register to listen to specific type of nodes or symbols. and analyse them. As far I know there aren't any helper classes for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the SemanticModel to analyse the type used for the field like this:

```
private async Task<bool> IsMentionedInDisposeCallAsync(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, FieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclarationSyntax)
{
    foreach (var variableDeclaratorSyntax in fieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration.Variables)
    {
        var declaredSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variableDeclaratorSyntax);
        if (declaredSymbol is IFieldSymbol fieldSymbol)
        {
            var isDisposeable = CheckIsTypeIDisposeable(fieldSymbol.Type as INamedTypeSymbol);
            //              SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync()
            var b = fieldSymbol.Locations;
            //              context.SemanticModel.Compilation.
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private string fullQualifiedAssemblyNameOfIDisposeable = typeof(IDisposable).AssemblyQualifiedName;
private bool CheckIsTypeIDisposeable(INamedTypeSymbol type)
{
    // Identify the IDisposable class. You can use any method to do this here
    // A type.ToDisplayString() == "System.IDisposable" might do it for you
    if(fullQualifiedAssemblyNameOfIDisposeable == 
        type.ToDisplayString() + ", " + type.ContainingAssembly.ToDisplayString())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(type.BaseType != null)
    {
        if (CheckIsTypeIDisposeable(type.BaseType))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    foreach(var @interface in type.AllInterfaces)
    {
        if (CheckIsTypeIDisposeable(@interface))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically you would search through all interfaces of the class and the base class recursively to find the type corresponding to IDisposeable - which should be somewhere in the hierarchy.

Comment: that's what i am doing - which works. However i am looking for a way to get symbols without manual traversal

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I don't see a way to do this without manually traversing the types